# $J^{-1}:\operatorname{Im}(J)\subset C_c^\infty(\Omega') \to C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is not continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\Omega, \Omega'$ be two open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\Omega \subset \Omega'$. Let $f \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and $\tilde{f}$ be the trivial extension of $f$ to $\Omega'$, that is, $\tilde{f}=f$ in $\Omega$ and $\tilde{f}=0$ in $\Omega'\setminus \Omega.$ Let $J:C_c^\infty(\Omega) \to C_c^\infty(\Omega')$ given by $J(f)=\tilde{f}$.

I already verified that $J$ is injective and continuous.

> **My question:** Suppose that $\Omega \neq \Omega'$, how to prove that $J^{-1}:\operatorname{Im}(J) \subset C_c^\infty(\Omega')  \to C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ is not continuous?

The spaces $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ and $C_c^\infty(\Omega')$ are equipped with their respective $LF$ topologies.

Comment: $J^{-1}$ is continuous if and only if $\Omega$ is a union of connected components of $\Omega'$.

Comment: @Jochen And how can we prove this result? Intuitively, if $\{\phi_n\}$ is a sequence in $C_c^\infty(\Omega')$ such that $\hbox{supp }(\phi_n) \subset \Omega$ and there exists $x_n \in \hbox{supp }(\phi_n)$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ with $x \in \partial \Omega$ and $\phi_n \rightarrow 0$ in $C_c^\infty(\Omega')$. The sequence $J^{-1}(\phi_n)$ cannot converge in $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ since for all compact $K \subset \Omega$ there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\hbox{supp } \phi_n \not\subset K$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: Dear @Jochen, could you take a look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4505957/characterization-of-extendible-distributions? You seem to be an expert in distributions theory.