# Characterization of extendible distributions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces

I found the following question which characterize the extension of a distribution in $\mathbb{R}$:

> Let $f \in L_{\text{loc}}^{1}(\mathbb{R}_{>0})$ such that $f \geq 0$ a.e. Show that $f$ extends to a distribution $F$ in $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if there exists $k \geq 0$ $$\int_{\varepsilon}^{1}f(x)dx=O(\varepsilon^{-k}),$$
> for $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

I would like to know if someone could give me some hint to solve this problem. The only thing I could think was evaluate the distribution $T_f$ generated by $f$ in functions like $\varphi_\varepsilon(x)$ satisfying $\operatorname{supp}(\varphi_\varepsilon) \subset (\varepsilon,1)$, but without success.

Another question I have is:

> Is there any generalization of this result to higher dimensions?

Comment: I would try *principle value distributions*.

Comment: @Jochen Even with this tip I have no idea how to start this exercise.

Comment: See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428029/characterization-of-extendible-distributions/428065?noredirect=1#comment1101062_428065) in mathoverflow.